# Add routing config via admin UI

Tags: 8, routes

I have a Drupal site with a specialised search query page that accepts about a dozen arguments as URL query parameters, most of which are optional.

Simplified routing YML file looks like this:

```
my_search_results_page.content:
  path: '/my-search'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_search\Controller\MySearchResultsController::content'
    _title: 'Search Results'
    location: null
    type: 'any'
    status: 'any'
    filter: 'any'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

The url query args `location`, `type`, `status` and `filter` are passed into the controller along with a bunch of others that I've ommitted for brevity. Location is a required field, hence the `null` default. All of the others are optional, and will get the value `any` if not specified in the query. This all works perfectly.

Now I have an additional requirement, to be able to create custom SEO-friendly preset URLs for specific search queries. For example, if they want to do a marketing push for widgets in London, they want a URL that looks like `/widgets-in-london`, which would resolve to a search results page where `location` is set to `London` and `type` is set to Widgets.

This seems like it could be achieved relatively easily by adding an additional routing entry to the my_search.routing.yml file for each preset URL they want, and and some extra code in my controller class to manage it. But the marketing team want to be able to create and edit these URLs on the fly, which makes a code-based solution non-optimal. But I'm at a loss as to how to do it more generally.

Can anyone help me come up with a flexible solution that will allow them to set up custom routes without them having to touch the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Redirect module

Comment: @Hudri - thanks for the suggestion. It does sound like what I want. Silly question: Does the redirect module mean that the page is redirected? Our marketing team want the final URL of the page to remain as the custom URL they specified, not just a redirect back to the page with query args. (they've been very specific about this, because of "mumble mumble SEO reasons")

Comment: Isn't this an alias then? You can add one manually in */admin/config/search/path/add*. Programmatically you can fill the alias table like the module Pathauto does for content or implement your own path processor.

Comment: @4k4 - Yes it should be. But unfortunately, URL alias doesn't work with URLs that include query args.

Comment: OK, then you need a custom path processor. For example: [PathProcessorFiles](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21PathProcessor%21PathProcessorFiles.php/function/PathProcessorFiles%3A%3AprocessInbound/8.7.x). This transfers the file name into a query arg because the file name with slashes doesn't work as route parameter.

Comment: So basically aliases are what you are looking for, but you need them to support query args. You could program your own database table and the UI to store such enhanced aliases. But an easier solution would be to use the existing alias system for transforming short urls to longer urls and then use a simple path processor with a few code lines as in the core example to transfer the information from the path to the query string.

Comment: For the record, I've ended up writing custom code for this; Aliases are what I need, but don't work for query args ("why not?" is a whole other question), but I've been able to add a custom route to my module that allows me to have a dynamic URL slug that maps to a predefined set of arguments that have been defined in config.